# How do I use IndexPathsForSelectedRows?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to use a custom method (created by another user) which copies instances of a struct I created called an [Ingredient]. The method is such;

```
convenience init(copyingIngredientsFrom meal: Meal, atIndexPaths indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        let sections = meal.ingredientSections
        self.init(mealTitle: selectedMeal!.mealTitle, mealID: selectedMeal!.mealID, mealImage: selectedMeal!.mealImage, ingredients: indexPaths.map {sections[$0.section][$0.row]})
```

The initial meal init is;

```
 init(mealTitle: String, mealID: Int, mealImage: UIImage?, ingredients: [Ingredient]) {
        self.mealTitle = mealTitle
        self.mealID = mealID
        self.mealImage = mealImage!
        self.ingredients = [Ingredient]()
    }
```

The new meal aims to create a new [Meal] object which copies over ingredients which are selected. I'm having some problems with the IndexPathsForSelectedRows crashing the app. I'd ideally also like to have rows "selected" by default but that is not necessary. This code executes before a segue as can be seen. Ideally I want to append the newMeal, instead of SelectedMeal, once the code is fixed. The problem with this code is that it currently crashes the app, and the indexPaths.count only says 1 if any value between 1 and x are selected and still crashes but prints nothing if I don't select any, once I've clicked the button. If I delete the if statement, then the app works fine with no problems.

```
if let list = detailTableViewIn.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
                print(indexPaths.count)
                let newMeal = Meal(copyingIngredientsFrom: selectedMeal!, atIndexPaths: list)
            }

        myMeals.insert(selectedMeal!, at: myMealsPosition)

        myMealsPosition += 1

        // Segues away
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MealCreated", sender: self)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I realised it is a problem with my init. I will try and do some researching first. Thanks for your help @Shades

Answer (score 0):

Look this example:

```
  let Meals = [Meal]


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("MealCreated", sender: indexPath)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
                let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
                let meal = Meals[indexPath!.row]

                if segue.identifier == "MealCreated"{

                    let DetailMeal = (segue.destinationViewController as! DetailMealController)
                    DetailMeal.mealTitle = meal.mealTitle
                    DetailMeal.mealID = meal.mealID
                    DetailMeal.mealImage = meal.mealImage
                    DetailMeal.ingredients = meal.ingredients

                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks @Carlo! Unfortunately, this isn't really what I was looking for, as I'm trying to use the method copyingIngredientsFrom() from my post. I tried implementing a prepare for segue, and the app still had the problem of crashing.

Comment: My answer is only an alternative to your method.